# Split string to array of characters in Spark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

How to split string column into array of characters?

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Vilnius',), ('Riga',), ('Tallinn',), ('New York',)], ['col_cities'])
df.show()
# +----------+
# |col_cities|
# +----------+
# |   Vilnius|
# |      Riga|
# |   Tallinn|
# |  New York|
# +----------+
```

Desired output:

```py
# +----------+------------------------+
# |col_cities|split                   |
# +----------+------------------------+
# |Vilnius   |[V, i, l, n, i, u, s]   |
# |Riga      |[R, i, g, a]            |
# |Tallinn   |[T, a, l, l, i, n, n]   |
# |New York  |[N, e, w,  , Y, o, r, k]|
# +----------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) with regex pattern having negative lookahead:

```
df.withColumn('split', F.split('col_cities', '(?!$)'))
```

---

```
+----------+------------------------+
|col_cities|split                   |
+----------+------------------------+
|Vilnius   |[V, i, l, n, i, u, s]   |
|Riga      |[R, i, g, a]            |
|Tallinn   |[T, a, l, l, i, n, n]   |
|New York  |[N, e, w,  , Y, o, r, k]|
+----------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

[`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) can be used by providing empty string `''` as separator. However, it will return empty string as the last array's element. So then `slice` is needed to remove the last array's element.

```py
split = "split(col_cities, '')"
split = F.expr(f'slice({split}, 1, size({split})-1)')

df.withColumn('split', split).show(truncate=0)
# +----------+------------------------+
# |col_cities|split                   |
# +----------+------------------------+
# |Vilnius   |[V, i, l, n, i, u, s]   |
# |Riga      |[R, i, g, a]            |
# |Tallinn   |[T, a, l, l, i, n, n]   |
# |New York  |[N, e, w,  , Y, o, r, k]|
# +----------+------------------------+
```