# Increase the date based on the length of Name column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: date, pyspark

I'm trying to add new columns based on the input Name and Date columns as below:

**Input:**

```
+------+-----------+
|Name  |Date       |
+------+-----------+
|PETER |1986-May-29|
+------+-----------+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+---------+-----------+
|Character|   New_Date|
+---------+-----------+
|        P|1986-May-29|
|        E|1986-May-30|
|        T|1986-May-31|
|        E|1986-Jun-01|
|        R|1986-Jun-02|
+---------+-----------+

df_withchars = df.withColumn("Character", F.explode(F.split('Name','')))\
                         .filter(F.col('Character') != '')

df_withchars.withColumn('New_Date', (lambda x: F.date_add(x['Date'], 1) for i in range(len(x[0])))).show()
```

Tried the above code and throwing *NameError: name 'x' is not defined*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) to create an array from the column and then [posexplode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode.html) to explode this array.

`posexplode` is similar to `explode` function but it returns one additional column - the position/index of an item. That means it will give you the number from 0 to 4 in your particular example. You can add this number to the date using `date_add` function.

Before we start lets import relevant functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, DateType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, date_add, posexplode
from datetime import date
```

Then create a data frame:

```
sample_data = [('PETER', date.today())]

sample_schema = StructType([
  StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
  StructField('Date', DateType(), True),
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=sample_data, schema=sample_schema)
```

Final step is to use `split` and `posexplode` functions to get the index of each character, and then add the index to date.

```
df \
.withColumn('SplittedName', split('Name', "(?!$)")) \
.select('Name', 'Date', posexplode('SplittedName')) \
.withColumn('NewDate', date_add('Date', col('pos'))).show()
```

Note that in the above code, I've used regex pattern `(?!$)` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564279/8843222)). You can use empty string `""` as well. However, it will return an additional empty item in the resulting array in `SplittedName` column, which will requires adding another step just to remove this empty, not relevant item.

The result:

[image]

## EDIT:

To get the resulting date in the desired format, you just need to use `date_format` (don't forget to import the function first) as follows:

```
df \
.withColumn('SplittedName', split('Name', "(?!$)")) \
.select('Name', 'Date', posexplode('SplittedName')) \
.withColumn('NewDate', date_format(date_add('Date', col('pos')), "yyyy-MMM-dd")).show()
```

New result:

[image]

Comment: Almost you did it! I want the month name in the output like 2023-**Feb**-02, 2023-**Feb**-03......